# Is there a way of using CAST (or CONVERT) in SQL to turn a character string into a time object?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, casting

I have a field in my Database that holds a 16 byte char array and I have stuck 2 unsigned chars into the first two bytes of the array. Now these 2 unsigned bytes holds the time value divided into a byte for the hour value and the other byte being for the minute value. When viewing these values in the database I get wierd symbols as the database thinks its dealing with a 16 byte char array so I was wondering what would I need to do in order to view the time value represented by the first 2 bytes of the array?
I have tried the following to no prevail.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [reference]
      ,CAST(extra1 as time)
FROM [DB NAME].[DB TABLE]
```

`extra1` is the name of the column in the database, which holds the 16 byte char array values, which you can see here I'am trying to cast as a time object, but it fails after clicking on execute.

Any help will be much appreciated, although please dont ask about why I have stuck the 2 unsigned bytes into a 16 byte char array, its a long story ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but should work:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [reference]
    ,CAST(
        (cast(ascii(substring(extra1 ,1,1)) as varchar) + ':' + CAST(ascii(substring(extra1 ,2,1)) as varchar)
        as time)
FROM [DB NAME].[DB TABLE]
```

Comment: if you have to use this many times I'd advice creating an SQL function to return a `time` from a `varchar`, to avoid having this ugliness all around

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help w0lf, its very much appreciated!